# Routing inside modules Codeigniter hmvc

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want a 'global link' to each module like this:

Inside **application/config/routes.php**

```
$route['search'] = 'searchPage';
```

if the user is typing search in the url it needs to go to module searchPage, there is where the routes inside the module comes in. Or that's my plan, I want a default routing inside that module.

Inside **modules/searchPage/config/routes.php**

```
$route['searchPage'] = 'Welcome/showMessage';
```

go to the Welcome controller with function showMessage.

```
-modules
--searchPage
---config
----routes.php
---controllers
---views
---models
```

inside my Welcome controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends MX_Controller {

    public function showMessage()
    {
        $this->load->view('test');
    }
}
?>
```

Version: Wiredesignz 5.5 and codeigniter 3.0.3

But this don't work. Can someone explain why this doesn't work?

**I found a solution:**

I have placed this code in application/config/routes.php

```
$modules_path = APPPATH.'modules/';     
$modules = scandir($modules_path);

foreach($modules as $module)
{
    if($module === '.' || $module === '..') continue;
    if(is_dir($modules_path) . '/' . $module)
    {
        $routes_path = $modules_path . $module . '/config/routes.php';
        if(file_exists($routes_path))
        {
            require($routes_path);
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

And inside modules/searchPage/config/routes.php

```
$route['searchPage'] = 'searchPage/Welcome/showMessage';
```

Comment: how did you go did you try any answers

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I have added the solution in my post

Comment: @da1lbi3 but why you don't put this route `$route['searchPage'] = 'searchPage/Welcome/showMessage';` inside the main ( and should be the only config directory) routes file as I propose on my answer ?

Comment: @DavidBm Because in my opinion it is cleaner and more logical, because you have your module with the route's referencing to that module. And If i set all the routes in the main, is it mixed togheter. So the structure is gone in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is not well performed

```
-modules
--searchPage
---config
----routes.php
---controllers
---views
---models
```

it should look like this

```
    -config
    --routes.php
    -modules
    --searchPage
    ---controllers
    ---views
    ---models
```

you can only have one config folder and has to be outside the modules folder, same as all the php files of configuration

Answer (score 0):

If your module is named `searchPage`

```
$route['searchPage'] = 'searchPage/welcome/showMessage';
$route['some_name'] = 'module/controller/function';
```

Directory Example

```
modules >

modules > searchPage >

modules > searchPage > controllers >

modules > searchPage > controllers > Welcome.php
```

If you did not remove index.php with a htaccess you may need to include index.php in you url.

With your config and routes in your modules folder it is best to use the one in the main `application > config > routes.php`  and `application > config > config.php`